# Finding which object an attribute belongs to in tkinter Python when using multiple objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My program consists of 3 Classes. The whole program is running within the MainWindow Class. The MainWindow Class first initialises itself, followed by the self.menubar object. The next object is a textbox which I have given the name self.journal.

Once the program is running I try to access the `open_file` method of `MainWindow` and this is done by accessing the `filemenu` method of `Menubar`. The problem occurs when I try to open a text file the following error: `AttributeError: 'Menubar' object has no attribute 'journal'` occurs.

I have tried to replace `self.journal` with `MainWindow.journal` and `TextBox.journal` and it does not seem to work.

```
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        ''''''
        ''''''

        self.menubar = Menubar(self) # instantaiated Menubar object

        '''''
        '''''
        self.journal = TextBox(self.frame, name='Journal')
        '''''
        '''''



    def open_file(self):
        filename = MainWindow.getFileNameOpen(self)
        if filename == '': # No file chosen
            filename = None
        else:
            self.MainWindow.journal.delete(1.0, END) # This line is the problem       
            fh = open(filename, 'r')
            textFromFile = fh.read().rstrip()          
            self.MainWindow.journal.insert(1.0, textFromFile)
            fh.close()



class Menubar:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(parent)
        self.fileMenu(self.menubar)

    def fileMenu(self, parent):
        filemenu = tk.Menu(parent, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Open', accelerator='Ctrl+O', underline=0, command=lambda: MainWindow.open_file(self))



class TextBox(tk.Text):

    def __init__(self, parent, name='', *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label(master=parent, text=name).pack()
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master=parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text.pack()
```

I have emphasised the line which is causing me the problem. It is under the `def open_file(self)` method

Comment: what is `Main` and why are you using global?

Comment: Sorry I've edited it now. Main was supposed to be MainWindow and I've deleted the global

Comment: Could you please update the complete code for the open_file function, which is causing the issue

Comment: Also, are you sure that `def open_file(self)` function is inside MainWindow Class and not MenuBar class? to me it looks like the latter, can you please also update the compelte traceback

Comment: There's no need to make `MenuBar` another class. Just add the menu bar and items in `Main`.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes I placed the `def open_file(self)` into the MainWindow class, however I call the method using the `def file_menu(self, parent)` method of the `MenuBar` class.

Comment: @ tobias_k yes I can do that and I made the programme originally just using functions. However I want to place the `MenuBar` class as a separate module so it looks less cluttered, but more so I just really want to understand how the objects interrelate with each other as I am a beginner

Comment: What is `Main` in your code? could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry Main is MainWindow, I just changed it for the upload onto here as I thought it was a bit of a better name

Comment: Please, correct indentation in your open_file method of MainWindow Class and Keep Object naming consistent in your code...I'm somehow confused !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try something like the below code -

class Menubar:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.pt = parent
    self.menubar = tk.Menu(parent)
    self.fileMenu(self.menubar)

def fileMenu(self, parent):
    filemenu = tk.Menu(parent, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label='Open', accelerator='Ctrl+O', underline=0, command=lambda: self.pt.open_file())
```

Notice that I am saving `parent` in `self` and then using `self.pt` instead of `Main.` , if that does not work, you can also try -

```
lambda: MainWindow.open_file(self.pt)
```

instead of the current lambda part.

The issue was with the code -

```
lambda: MainWindow.open_file(self)
```

What this does is that it tries to call open_file function inside MAinWindow class passing the current `MenuBar` class's instance (object) as the parameter.

When you call a function inside a class, using object , lets say like this -

```
obj.func(**params)
```

Internally, how python calls it would be equivalent to `ItsClass.func(obj, **params)` , hence inside the `open_file()` function, when you were accessing self object (passed in through the parameter) , it was not an instance of `MainWindow` , but instead an instance of `MenuBar`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you also explain what I was doing wrong? Was it because I was calling a class attribute rather than the object attribute?

Comment: thanks for the answer I would make it a community wiki however after a quick googling I found that only the moderator can make it a community wiki

Comment: Sorry, I mean't I made it*